# Puppet SVN check out with vcsrepo not working

Tags: svn, puppet

I'm trying to use the vcsrepo module to check out an SVN repo. Heres the pp code I'm using:

```
    package { $repo_package:
            ensure => installed,
    }

    vcsrepo { "${doc_root}${fqdn}/src":
            ensure     => present,
            provider   => $repo_provider, #svn
            source     => $repository, #svn+ssh://remoterepo.com/path/to/trunk
            user       => $deploy_user,
            owner => 'www-data',
            group => 'www-data',
            require    => [ File["/home/${deploy_user}/.ssh/${deploy_private_key}"], Package["${repo_package}"] ], #making sure ssh key is there and that svn is installed
    }
```

And when I run it, I get this error:

```
Error: /Vcsrepo[/checkout/destination/path]: Could not evaluate:
Execution of '/usr/bin/svnlook uuid /checkout/destination/path'
returned 1: svnlook: E000002: Can't open file 
'/checkout/destination/path/format': No such file or directory
```

I looked into svnlook which is for looking at repos, and to me it seems the error is that this code is trying to make a repo in the /checkout/destination/path, instead of just trying to checkout code to there.

To summarize my question: Is the vcsrepo module trying to create a new repo or is it supposed to be just checking out the files to the specified destination path?

If the latter, where am I going wrong?

Comment: So the issue is solved, two problems: the vcsrepo doesn't support the user option with svn, so I have to make a .ssh/config file for an ssh identity. Secondly I had previously declared the src folder, and since it already existed it treated the call more as a update, which failed. so once removed the src folder it was good.

Comment: you should consider submitting an answer to your own question and accepting it as the answer so future SO user's can benefit.

Comment: And raise an issue to https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-vcsrepo and raise pull request to fix it if you can. You can learn a lot from this way, and I did that a lot.

Comment: Are you sure the svn provider doesn't support user, the docs say it does: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-vcsrepo#connect-via-ssh-4

Comment: @ptierno Yeah, I just wasnt sure if people do that haha, so thanks for letting me know

Comment: @BMW I did look at the code like you suggested and  not sure if my issue is actually an issue, or just me missing some facts, Ill take a look into it more this weekend

Comment: Looks like a bug in that codes, raise an issue to get suggestions from the repo's owner and related developers will be the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I did solve the problem, and It was due to already having created the `${doc_root}${fqdn}/src` directory. When the directory is already there, it treats the command as an update (I believe, thus requiring the format), so once I removed the before hand creation of the folder it worked. I should also note since I thought the svn users wasn't working I created an identity file (.ssh/config) for the root and that worked for me.

And as @Peter Souter mentioned, there is support for the user parameter user, I have yet to get it to work.

I'm going to try playing around with it some more in the future when I get the time . If anyone else has anything to add please feel free.

One more thing!! to actually get it working on a fresh puppet setup (with the .ssh/config file), I had to add the line:

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

to the `.ssh/config`, without it the checkout would fail, I believe due to the fact without the above line, it would ask to accept the server fingerprint, and puppet would then consider that a fail and move on.

Please let me know if I'm wrong on anything here, I don't want to be passing around incorrect info.

Comment: you still haven't accepted this post as the answer to your question! It may sound silly to answer your own question, but it helps future visitor's to the site who read your question to see a concrete answer.

Comment: It says i must wait 24hrs to accept my own answer haha